# angular translate not working when its loaded in slow internet connection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, translate, angular-translate

I am using $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en'); in my app.js, but in regular 3g or slow internet connection the file corresponding to it gets loaded but changes do not get reflected on the page. I am using this async loader directive

```
app.factory('asyncLoader', function($q, $timeout, $http, envService){
  return function(options) {
  var deferred = $q.defer(), translations;
  var pathUrl = envService.read('lang_file_path');

  var resturl = pathUrl + 'language-' + options.key + '.json';
  $http.get(
    resturl,{cache:true}).success(function(translations) {
      deferred.resolve(translations);
      }).error(function(translations) {
        deferred.reject(translations);
      });
    $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve(translations);
      }, 2000);

      return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

Setting done in app.js

```
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
$translateProvider.useLoader('asyncLoader');
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitizeParameters');
```

Comment: do you get a timeout from the http request? If the request takes more than 2s, your promise will be resolved with undefined within the `$timeout(function() {` before the response is returned.

Comment: the locale file I am using is of size 97Kb, so do I need to increase the time in timeout function?

Comment: I'm not sure,  imo, a better UX would be to reject the promise and on the UI, tells the users about the slow/bad connection and to try again, rather than resolve the promise with undefined value.

Comment: try using then instead of success, 
`$http.get( resturl,{cache:true}).then(function(translations) { });`

Comment: yep that would be better, rather to increase delay...thanks Anthiny C for the help.

Comment: ok @Sravan.. let me try

Comment: using then function instead of success, anf removed the delay function, this worked. Are there any more options to resolve this issue?? because then function will wait for the promise to get resolved, what If I have a bigger file than 97Kb.